# Div with nowrap still wraps

Tags: html, css

I want to make the div stay the same size while I resize the window.
My css for the div:

```
.header {
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #B71C1C, #0D47A1, #0D47A1);
  }
```

and here is the output before the wrap:

[image]

and after the wrap:

[image]

what I want is to header div always stay the same size no matter the browser's width.

Comment: Why not add a width (or min-width)?

Comment: We can't do much with one CSS rule. Post a [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 3):

The "white-space:nowrap" property is meant for text wrapping, not for general responsiveness of your elements. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

You either want to add a fixed "width" property (f.e. in pixels), or a "min-width" property to your element.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `white-space: nowrap` property is used to stop text from wrapping. In your case you might want to set a fixed width for that div so that it will not change based on the window size.